# How can I get the row number of results querying with DQL(Doctrine)

Tags: symfony, doctrine, dql

example: SELECT title,ROW_NUM FROM article ORDER BY count_read.
What should ROW_NUM be replace by ?

I don't like to after getting the results generate the index by program, because I want to  insert into a table Rank with the result data by querying the example DQL above.

What I want to achieve maybe like :

```
"INSERT INTO RANK r (title, index, lastIndex)
SELECT title,ROW_NUM,(SELECT index FROM RANK WHERE id = :id - 1) FROM article ORDER BY count_read"
```

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might use variables, like this:

```
"
SET @row_num := 1;
INSERT INTO RANK r (title, index, lastIndex)
SELECT title, 
       (@row_num := @row_num + 1),
       (SELECT index FROM RANK WHERE id = :id - 1) 
FROM article ORDER BY count_read
"
```

Comment: Thanks very much!! But I found that DQL doesn't support the INSERT statement :(

Comment: It's not necessary to use DQL - like in case you described.  If you need more or less difficult query you don't have to use dql (actually you never have to use it if there is no need to do so). You can use 'database_connection' service to use usual pdo methods like execute, fetchAll, fetchOne and so on instead of Doctrine wrapper methods. But anyway it's only your choice.